# No provider available for resource-env-ref in OpenEJB

Tags: ejb, openejb

I have 2 EJBs, EJB-2 is EJB 2.0, EJB-3 is EJB 3.0. The use case is EJB-3 needs to call EJB-2, it works on WebLogic 11g. But I get the exception "No provider available for resource-env-ref" exception in OpenEJB.

error message:

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: No provider available for resource-env-ref 'EJB-2' of type 'javax.ejb.SessionBean' for 'EJB-3'.
```

weblogic-ejb-jar.xml of EJB-3

```
<weblogic-enterprise-bean>
  <wls:ejb-name>EJB-3</wls:ejb-name>
  <resource-env-description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>EJB-2</resource-env-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>EJB-2</jndi-name>
  </resource-env-description>
</weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```

ejb-jar.xml of EJB-3

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>EJB-2</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.ejb.SessionBean</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Is there any advise for this issue? I use both OpenEJB 3.1.3 and 4.0 beta 1